# Custom MPI Path in CMake Project

Tags: compilation, cmake, mpi

I'm building a project that uses MPI.

Here's the CMakeLists.txt

```
if(__OPENNN_MPI__)    
   find_package(MPI)    
       if(MPI_FOUND)
        message("Using MPI")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)
        set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_LINK_FLAGS}")
        add_definitions(-D__OPENNN_MPI__ )
    endif() 
endif()
```

What argument to cmake do I pass to enable this block of code.

My MPI Installation is in a custom path, say `/path/to/MPI`

Do I simply add the MPI path to my $PATH and run `cmake .` or is there a flag that I should set, like we would set `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH`

Answer (score 2):

To tell CMakes `FindMPI` about a custom installation, it is sufficient to make sure that your custom `mpicc` and `mpicxx` is in `$PATH`. Alternatively, you can supply them as such:

```
cmake -DMPI_C_COMPILER=/path/to/bin/mpicc -DMPI_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/bin/mpicxx
```

CMake will pick up the rest based on the compiler wrappers. You should however **not set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` / `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`** to the MPI compiler wrappers. Instead:

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

And for each C++ target:

```
target_link_libraries(target ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
if(MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif()
if(MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

C targets similarly.